# Call to new HttpRequest fails

Tags: php

I am trying to get a PHP script working. The purpose of the script is to call out to a web service. I've reduced the script down to it's simpliest components and it is still failing. Here it is:

```
<?php
print "Hello";
$request = new HttpRequest('http://www.pivotaltracker.com/services/v3/source_commits', HttpRequest::METH_POST);
print "Done";
?>
```

The output is:

```
D:\svn\svndb\hooks>"c:\Program Files\PHP\php.exe" -f test.php
Hello
D:\svn\svndb\hooks>
```

As you can see, the script fails when trying to instantiate an instance of HttpRequest. However, no exception is thrown.

I am not a PHP program... I'm just trying to get this feature working. I suspect I have no loaded an extension library that I need... but I can't figure out which one that would be, if indeed that is the problem.

I am running on Windows 2003. I am running PHP 5.3.3.

I did run phpinfo() but am hesitant to post the results here since it is so large. Is there a section of the phpinfo() output that would be helpful to provide?

Comment: Put a `error_reporting(E_ALL);` in front and see what happens.

Comment: What does it do if you set `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` right at the start?

Answer (score 6):

Put a `error_reporting(E_ALL);` in front and see what happens.

My bet is that the `HTTPRequest` class doesn't exist. The HTTP extension is a [PECL package that needs to be installed separately](http://www.php.net/manual/en/http.install.php).

Answer (score 2):

Thank you everyone for your answers. They were all spot on. I thought I'd summnarize what I did in the end in case it helps someone else.

The problem was indeed that I had not installed the http PECL extension. Unfortunately, I am on windows and there was no distriubtion of this extension and I didn't want to install the microsoft tools on this box to be able to compile the source. So, I went with the suggestion listed above and implemented it using curl.

The script I was working on was to integration svn to http://www.pivotaltracker.com using the excellent php script found at http://phpjack.com/content/pivotal-tracker-and-subversion. I modified that script as follows (in case someone else is in a similar spot):

```
$request = new HttpRequest('http://www.pivotaltracker.com/services/v3/source_commits', HttpRequest::METH_POST);
$headers = array(
  'X-TrackerToken' => $token,
  'Content-type'  => 'application/xml'
);
$request->setHeaders($headers);
$request->setBody("<source_commit><message>$message</message><author>$author</author><commit_id>$rev</commit_id></source_commit>");
$request->send();
```

became

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/xml","X-TrackerToken: $token"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
print $result;
```

Thanks again for all the excellent and timely advise.

Answer (score 1):

1. Error reporting by error_reporting( E_ALL );
2. Enable display errors ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Better to change these settings from php.ini.
If it's not working look at apache logs (error.log)

Answer (score 1):

You could use cURL for that simple purpose:

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.pivotaltracker.com/services/v3/source_commits";
$ch = curl_init();

// set the target url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

// howmany parameter to post
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

// parameters
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "someParameter=someValue");

$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

print $result;
?>
```

Or use `fsockopen()` to connect to a server and `fwrite` to send a raw http post request.

Comment: Thank you. This was perfect. I ended up implementing this and it works great.